# How to hide gettext infos in php

Tags: php, gettext, php-gettext

I am writing simple script using gettext PHP function. All works well but i try to monitore what is changed for what.

For example when user change 2 fields

```
Type: (old) Agreement (new) Anex
Notes: (old) #empty field# (new) Agreement ID: 123
```

My editinfo generator looks like that

```
foreach($checkArray as $row => $value)
{
    if ($addData[$row] != $checkArray[$row])
    {
        $editInfo .= ' <b>' . _("FILED") . '</b> ' . _("$row") . ' <b>' . _("CHANGED FROM") . '</b> ' . _($checkArray[$row]) . ' <b>' . _("FOR") . '</b> ' . _($addData[$row]) . '<br />';
    }
}
```

But i recieved info like that

```
<b>POLE</b> Type <b>ZMIENIONE Z</b> Umowa <b>NA</b> Aneks <br />
<b>POLE</b> Notes <b>ZMIENIONE Z</b> Project-Id-Version: 
POT-Creation-Date: 
PO-Revision-Date: 
Language-Team: 
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-Generator: Poedit 2.0.9
Plural-Forms: nplurals=3; plural=(n==1 ? 0 : n%10>=2 && n%10<=4 && (n%100<10 || n%100>=20) ? 1 : 2);
Last-Translator: 
Language: pl
 <b>NA</b> Agreement ID: 123<br />
```

As You can see all translates works well, but when field is empty, gettext function return some crazy stuff but i would like to have

```
<b>Pole</b> Type <b>ZMIENIONE Z</b> Umowa <b>NA</b> Aneks<br>
<b>Pole</b> Notes <b>ZMIENIONE Z</b> <b>NA</b> Agreement ID: 123<br>
```

So my question is what i should to change in PHP or PHP Settings in my server to hide that gettext info. I would to set "If gettext can't find translation just write pure text" in this case nothing.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we can read in [gettext manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#MO-Files):

> This also has another advantage, as the empty string in a PO file GNU gettext is usually translated into some system information attached to that particular MO file, and the empty string necessarily becomes the first in both the original and translated tables, making the system information very easy to find.

Probably your `.po` file contains `msgid` which is an empty string and its value is just the system information.

So when you call `_("")` you get that. You can try passing some default field if it's not found:

```
_($checkArray[$row] ?: "default")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try and reply with result.